# In FasterRCNN, why is the short edge size 600 and the max size 1000?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I read the following code:

https://github.com/endernewton/tf-faster-rcnn/blob/a3279943cbe6b880be34b53329a4fe3f971c2c37/lib/model/config.py#L63

600 is the pixel size of an image's shortest side, and 1000 is the max pixel size of the longest side of a scaled input image.
Could anybody explain this? and how to determine these sizes? Shall we change these sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are used in `prep_im_for_blob` function in [here](https://github.com/endernewton/tf-faster-rcnn/blob/0e61bacf863f9f466b54770f35a130514e85cac6/lib/utils/blob.py#L33). Where `target_size` is `__C.TRAIN.SCALES = (600,)`, and max_size is `__C.TRAIN.MAX_SIZE = 1000`. What it does is scales the image so that the minimum size of the resized image is equal to `__C.TRAIN.SCALES`. However if the resulting image becomes bigger than `__C.TRAIN.MAX_SIZE` it scales so that maximum size of resized image is equal to `__C.TRAIN.MAX_SIZE`. If your input image typically falls within 600~1000 pixels in range, you don't need to change these values.